# Non-modal transparent informative alert in iOS

Tags: ios, alert, non-modal

I would like to implement a non-blocking, transparent alert in iOS in which I can insert a message, similar to applications such as Tweetbot.  Preferably, these alerts should come with a different error and info view and should animate down from the top of the screen.  Are there any libraries that I can use which create an alert like this?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally found the [GCDiscreetNotificationView](https://github.com/gcamp/GCDiscreetNotificationView) library useful.  However, it does not currently support different info and error styles.

Answer (score 2):

Add a subview that displays your text

```
- (void) showOverlayMessage
{
    // add subview with animation from top
}

- (void) hideOverlayMessage
{
    // remove subview with animation from top
}
```

// Call hideOverlayMessage after 1-2 seconds

```
[self performSelector: @selector(hideOverlayMessage) withObject: nil afterDelay: 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets the BlockAlerts are very tweetbot-esque.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a non-blocking alert.